# Why isn't django-nose running the doctests in my models?

Tags: django, nose, django-testing

I'm trying to use doctests with django-nose.  All my doctests are running, except not any doctests within a model (unless it is abstract).

```
class TestModel1(models.Model):
    """
    >>> print 'pass'
    pass
    """
    pass

class TestModel2(models.Model):
    """
    >>> print 'pass'
    pass
    """
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    pass
```

The first doctest does not run and the second does.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're getting bitten by this? http://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose/issues/2
If so, try upgrading django-nose