# Nose not running Django doctests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, nose

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614363/why-isnt-django-nose-running-the-doctests-in-my-models). However, in my case, none of my models' `doctest` are running.

I'm using [Django 1.3 beta 1](http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2010/dec/22/13-beta-1/).

```
# settings.py
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ##...a bunch of django apps
    'django_nose',
    'south',
    'my_project.my_app',
)
```

One of my model's doctest:

```
class ItemType(models.Model):
    '''
    >>> temType.objects.all().count() == 0
    True
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Should fail because of `initial_data` fixture but just in case, I tried it with the following:

```
class ItemType(models.Model):
    '''
    >>> ItemType.objects.all().count() == -1
    True
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I tried running the following:

```
./manage.py test --with-doctest my_app
```

With the Django test runner, I just type the following for my doctests to be processed:

```
./manage.py test my_app
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

In your settings, just include this setting:

```
NOSE_ARGS = ['--with-doctest', other_nose_args]
```

See [django-nose documentation](http://howthebodyworks.github.com/django-nose-lite/installation.html) to more options

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late by now but, can you run your tests with higher `--verbosity`?

If you find messages saying files are being skipped due to being executable, try adding `--exe` to your NOSE_ARGS or `chmod -x the_file.py`.