# django doctests not being run

Tags: python, django, testing, nose, doctest

I'm having a problem running django doctests with django-nose.  Unit tests added to a /tests directory are running fine, but doctests are not.

I am trying to run doctests on my "season" module:

```
python manage.py test season
```

and get this output:

```
nosetests --verbosity 1 season --with-doctest
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I'm just trying a basic doctest to try to get this to work, e.g.:

```
    """
    >>> 1+1 == 2
    True
    """
```

This is in my models.py.  I've tried other doctests actually testing the code and still don't see any tests run.  When I run with --verbosity 3, I see one line that may be the issue:

```
nose.selector: INFO: <models.py path> is executable; skipped
```

I couldn't find any more info on what this means though.

Relevant snippets from settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'south',
    'django_nose',
    'season',
)

# Django-nose configuration
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = ['--with-doctest']
```

django_nose is after south in INSTALLED_APPS as specified in the django-nose documentation.  I'm using the --with-doctest argument as suggested here: [Nose not running Django doctests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588305/nose-not-running-django-doctests), and have updated my django-nose to the latest as suggested here: [Why isn't django-nose running the doctests in my models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614363/why-isnt-django-nose-running-the-doctests-in-my-models)

These are the versions I am using:
django 1.3
python 2.7.1
django-nose 0.1.3
nose 1.1.2

I feel like I'm missing some basic setup here.  Let me know if any other info is needed.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I realize that the OP specified 1.3, but since this answer comes up in a search for 'django doctests do not run' here's my answer for 1.6 from one of the answers in [Django doctests in views.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380527/django-doctests-in-views-py). in this version of Django doctests are *not* automatically included, so in $APP/tests.py you need:

```
import doctest
def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite())
    return tests
```

[this only finds the doctests in tests.py itself; to have it run doctests on other modules, say myapp/models.py, you need to `from myapp import models` and `tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(models))`]

Comment: That would make nose irrelevant (which is fine with me—I was only trying it because it was supposed to solve this problem), but STILL isn't finding any doctests. I can specify the specific modules, but that's not automatic...

Comment: right, the above only finds the doctests in tests.py itself.

Comment: Great! Just confirming that this still works in Django 3.2

Answer (score 2):

The verbosity message is telling you your models.py file is being ignored because it's executable. This means you need to do:

```
chmod -x models.py
```

Unless you have a specific reason for that file to be set as executable, in which case adding `--exe` to your `NOSE_ARGS` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

`nosetests --verbosity 1 season --with-doctest`

`Usage: manage.py test [options] [appname ...]`

Perhaps you just need to move `season` to then end.

Comment: I run "manage.py test season", with the --with-doctest argument in the  NOSE_ARGS.  If I remove --with-doctest from NOSE_ARGS, and run "manage.py test --with-doctest season", I get the same result.  So I think this is how "manage.py test" will run nosetests.  Any other possibilities?